# How to match 2 users if they both pressed 'Heart' button

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

My app is very similar to Tinder, and only got the "matching" part left for it to be finished. When the user touches the 'Heart' button, a card with their profile is displayed on the Notifications View to the other user, for them to accept it or not.

In case of yes, the will both 'match' as in Tinder. My problem is in how to make that happen.

`Person` is presented to the `User`, and the home view displays the people, that `UserManager` holds.

```
struct Person: Identifiable, Hashable {
       var username: String
       var age: Int
}
```

```
struct User {
    let username: String // These are let because they're being saved on UserManager
    let age: Int
}
```

```
class UserManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userInfo: UserInfo?
    @Published var people: [Person] = [] // All People
    @Published var matches: [Person] = [] // Matched people
```

Now, here in UserManager, I fetchAllUsers from Firebase and basically init the people's data by the documentSnapshot.

```
ref.getDocuments { documentsSnapshot, error in
            if let error = error { }
            
            documentsSnapshot?.documents.forEach({ snapshot in
                let data = snapshot.data()
                
                self.people.append(.init(data: data))
            })
        }
```

And finally, in `HomeView`, the user taps the button and appends the other person in the matches array, which doesn't make sense cause the other person hasn't even accepted them yet.

```
struct HomeView: View {
       var body: some View {

                 CircleButtonView(type: .heart) {
                    if let person = userMng.people.last {
                        userMng.swipe(person, _direction: .like)

                        userMng.matches.append(person) 
                        // Should change this to another array?
                    }
                 }
       }
}
```

Tried saving it to Firebase and then retrieving the data from the users once matched but I can't especify what person the user has liked, for me to make that network call.

#### **How can I append** the liked person to another array and then append it     to 'matches' once confirmed that they both like each other?

Comment: make an array/dic (liked users) in user document on firebase with person usernames that he liked. 
if want to track both then create a collection name pair kinda somehting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a new table in firebase with the name of `firendRequest`, where table child id will be userID and below it, we will have ids of all users who has sent him the friends request. Please have a look the the schema in below image which will make your concept more clear.

[image]

The way, you are getting all the user will add up more computation when number of users start increasing and its not recommend to do such large computation on mobile devices. One more thing, Firesbase is `NO-SQL database` so you need to duplicate your data to avoid computations. **Making duplicate date does not mean you are not implementing the thing right :)**

Comment: Thank you Qazi very clear! I'll get home and try it to let you know

Comment: So I'm implementing this to my Firestore but I don't know how could I create a map value for the data in user_2. I will be storing it as a subcollection of each document with the uid, but I was simply calling all the data as .updateData(), where there were just strings or int

Comment: yes, you can use `.updateData()` every time. it will add new recored if does't exist otherwise update the recored

Comment: Yup, everything's working fantastic. Only thing I'm stuck with is to return the request_status of the friend request. I guess by checking if the user that sent the request is in friends, and if false, display "pending", but 'how to check it' is what I can't figure out

Comment: you can put a extra key value `friend_status : false` in each `friend_request` entry.